# How many undirected graphs are there on 3 vertices?

Tags: algorithm, combinations, analysis, combinatorics

An undirected graph contains 3 vertices. How many undirected graphs can be formed? I tried the combination formula but the answer was wrong.

Comment: There's 3 edges, and each edge can be there or not. So 2^3=8 graphs. Unless you're counting graphs up to isomorphism, in which case there's only 4.

Comment: then if it's 4 vertices is it 2^4?

Comment: No, because there's not 4 potential edges in a graph with 4 vertices. There's 6 edges, so it's 2^6.

Comment: if there are 4 vertices then maximum edges can be 4C2 I.e. 6 egdes. for all 6 edges you have an option either to have it or not have it in your graph. each option gives you a separate graph. hench total number of  graphs are 2 raised to power 6 so total 64 graphs.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68017/counting-non-isomorphic-graphs-with-prescribed-number-of-edges-and-vertices

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about graph theory, not programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Graph with N vertices may have up to `C(N,2) = (N choose 2) = N*(N-1)/2` edges (if loops aren't allowed).

So overall number of possible graphs is `2^(N*(N-1)/2)`.

Comment: I think it would have been helpful to point out, we can have a maximum of \$N \choose 2 = \frac{N!}{(N-2)!2! = \frac{N\times (N-1)}{2}\$ edges since, we need the number of ways we can choose 2 vertices out of the N available ones, to form a possible edge. [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/FqO3wmn.png)

Comment: What if you allow for loops?

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 What loops? Self-loops (buckles)?  `2^(N*(N + 1)/2)`

Answer (score 2):

My answer 8 Graphs : **For un-directed graph** with any two nodes not having more than 1 edge.
A graph with N vertices can have at max `n`**C**`2` edges. `3`**C**`2` is (3!)/((2!)*(3-2)!) => 3. 
So you can compute number of Graphs with 0 edge, 1 edge, 2 edges and 3 edges.

At max the number of edges for N nodes = N*(N-1)/2 Comes from `n`**C**`2` and for each edge you have option of choosing it in your graph or not choosing it and with each option you get a unique graph and it gives the formula : 2^(N*(N-1)/2) graphs possible.

If nodes are named a, b, and c then

All Disconnected nodes : 0 edge

```
a  b  c
```

**= 1 Graph**

only 2 nodes connected : 1 edge

```
a--b  c
b--c  a
c--a  b
```

**= 3 graphs**

all 3 nodes connected : 2 edges

```
a--b--c (c--b--a will be same)
a--c--b ( b--c--a will be same)
b--a--c (c--a--b will be same)
```

**= 3 nodes**

all 3 nodes connected : 3 edges

```
a--b--c--a
```

**= 1 Graph**

So total **8 Graphs.** Other way of looking at it is for each edge you have 2 options either to have it or not have it there by making 2 raised to the power 3 (2 choices and 3 edges) making 8 as answer.

**For Directed graph** we will have more cases to consider, I am trying below to find the number of graphs if we could have Directed graph (Note that below is for the case where we do not have more than 1 edge between 2 nodes, in case we have more than 1 edge between 2 nodes then answer will differ)

**0 edge**

a b c **= 1 Graph**

**1 edge**

```
a-->b c
a<--b c
b-->c a
b<--c a
c-->a b
c<--a b
```

**= 6 Graphs**

**2 edges**

```
a-->b-->c
a-->b<--c
a<--b-->c
a<--b<--c
b-->a-->c
b-->a<--c
b<--a-->c
b<--a<--c
a-->c-->b
a-->c<--b
a<--c-->b
a<--c<--b
```

**= 12 Graphs**

**3 Edges**

```
a-->b-->c-->a
a-->b-->c<--a
a-->b<--c-->a
a-->b<--c<--a
a<--b-->c-->a
a<--b-->c<--a
a<--b<--c-->a
a<--b<--c<--a
```

**= 8 Graphs**

**Total = 1 + 6 + 12 + 8 = 27 Graphs**

Comment: This is what I got for my first answer but it was counted wrong and I don't understand why.

Comment: I edited my answer. I computed graphs with linear connected worng previously.

Comment: There's 1 graph with "all disconnected nodes". You count 3, but you're accidentally counting nodes rather than graphs.

Comment: @Emma I have done needed correction in my answer, please read it hopefully it will clear your understanding.

Comment: Did my answer helped you, or do you need more help for your query.

Comment: is it the same case for a directed graph?

Comment: For directed graph there will be more cases as a-->b and b-->a will be different graphs. Likewise a-->b--c and c-->b-->a will also be different so answer will be different for directed graph,

Comment: @Emma I have edited my answer to include the case for directed graph as well, have  a look.

Comment: Also you can see why N*(N-1)/2 number of maximum edges and   2^(N*(N-1)/2) number of possible graphs works. In the edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You should decide first if you want to count *labelled* or *unlabelled* objects. Let's assume that your graph is simple, that is: no loops or multiple edges.

If you are counting labelled objects, then you are counting the number of 
symmetric 0-1 matrices with 0s on the diagonal (that is, the adjacency matrices of the graphs). There are 2^(1+2...+n-1)=2^(n(n-1)/2) such matrices, hence, the same number of undirected, simple graphs. For n=3 this gives you 2^3=8 graphs.

If you are counting unlabelled objects, then you are counting the number of graphs *up to graph isomorphism*. This is a much more difficult question. Some computational data is available in the website of *Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences* (OEIS) website for larger n: https://oeis.org/A000088. From this website we infer that there are 4 unlabelled graphs on 3 vertices (indeed: the empty graph, an edge, a cherry, and the triangle).

Answer (score 1):

For the directed graph case, wouldn't the number of graphs be given by the equation 2 ^ (n ^ 2) by the same logic as that of the undirected graph case (assuming self-loops are allowed)? In particular, all vertexes can have n outgoing edges (again, including the self-loop). Therefore n ^ 2 (or n * n) represents the maximum number of edges possible for the graph. Since we make a choice for each edge whether to include it or not, the maximum number of graphs is given by 2 ^ (n ^ 2). Can anyone confirm this?